# jQuery - the option "blind" in "setInterval" still running

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, setinterval

I added to my page this a part of code

```
    setInterval(function() {
     $('div.info').hide("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 1000);   
}, 2000);
```

If on a page exist **div.info**, so that div is displaying and after 2 seconds this div should be hidden with speed 1 seconds.

But I am struggling with problem, that this action is running over and over again - on the page is discovered **div.info**, after 2 seconds is this DIV hide and immediately is again displayed and after another 2 seconds again hidden... And this is over and over again...

Can someone help me, please, why is this action still restarted?
Thank you.

Comment: Bit confused what you are after here, but are you sure you weren't looking for `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`?

Comment: Of course Niklas, `setTimeout` is solution... Thank for you note! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using setTimeout(function, delayInMilliseconds) instead of setInterval. setInterval sets a function to run every x milliseconds whereas setTimeout only runs once.

Comment: Thanks, `setTimeout` is the answer :)